# laravel boot() service: cannot access variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my application Navigation is compiled via Laravel ServiceProvider `compose()` method:

```
view()->composer('partials.nav', function($view) {
    $navData = // retrieve categories from DB... 
    $view->with($navData);
});
```

I do receive the variable `$navData` to my `nav.blade.php` and compile navigation successfully. However some of the data passed to navigation I want to use on a page that `@includes` the navigation, for example `page.blade.php`:

```
@include('partials.nav')

<div id="main">
{{ $navData['category'] }}
</div>
```

But I throws error: `Undefined variable: $navData`. Is there a way to access this variable outside the `nav.blade.php` without making any additional calls?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$navData` in `page.blade.php`, not in `partials.nav`. So to make it work replace

```
view()->composer('partials.nav', function($view) {
```

with

```
view()->composer('page.blade.php', function($view) {
```

or

```
view()->composer('*', function($view) {
```

if you want to make `$navData` available everywhere.

Comment: If I replace `'partials.nav'` with `'page.blade.php'`, then `$navData` will be accessible only on `page.blade.php`, but I need it on `nav` which is included in all pages. I tried `'*'`, but it throws error. I'm new to laravel, so I might be getting something wrong here

Comment: "I tried '*', but it throws error." - paste error message here

Comment: `FatalErrorException in NavigationComposer.php line 13:
Cannot redeclare App\Http\Composers\list_categories() (previously declared in C:\project\app\Http\Composers\NavigationComposer.php:13)`. Once I change `'*'` back to `'partials.nav'` it works normally.

Comment: It's another error, it means that you have two methods with the same name. Rename one of them to solve this conflict.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
view()->composer('partials.nav', function($view) {
$data['navData'] = // retrieve categories from DB... 
$view->with($data);
});
```